# Codec addition In android application

Tags: java, android, sip, codec

I have developed an application for void calling using SIP protocol .Currently I am using GSM codec which is provided by android by default.But now I want to use **G729** codec and I don't have any idea how to use that codec .So can any one give me some idea or provide me any link so that I can use that codec??

Answer (score 0):

First, Android does not support this codec because of its licence:

> G.729 includes patents from several companies and is licensed by Sipro Lab Telecom. Sipro Lab Telecom is the authorized Intellectual Property Licensing Administrator for G.729 technology and patent pool. In a number of countries, the use of G.729 may require a license fee and/or royalty fee.

You have been warned.

Technically you may use one of many java implementations of G.729 like this one: [Encoder](https://code.google.com/p/mobicents/source/browse/trunk/servers/media/codecs/g729/src/main/java/org/mobicents/media/server/impl/dsp/audio/g729/Encoder.java?r=16762) and [Decoder](https://code.google.com/p/mobicents/source/browse/trunk/servers/media/codecs/g729/src/main/java/org/mobicents/media/server/impl/dsp/audio/g729/Decoder.java?r=16762)

Comment: thank you for sharing this information .Do you know how can I change codec in SIP implementation?Cant I add this codec  in android application.

Comment: This is another question for another topic. Please decide if this one have been answered or not.

Comment: actually this is not my answer as from begining my question was how to use codec in android app.

Comment: Happy waiting for plug&play implementation :).